# Python: How to display the top numbers from text files using regex

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, file

My assignment is to display the top views from two different text files. The text files are formatted as 'file' followed by pathfolder, views, open/close. What I'm having trouble with is displaying the top views AND the titles of the path_folders have to be in alphabetical order just in case if the views were the same.

I've already used glob to read the two different files. I am even using regex to make sure the files are read the way it is supposed to. I also know I can use the sort/sorted to make it in alphabetical order. My main concern is mostly displaying the top views from the text files.

Here are my files:

**file1.txt**

```
file Marvel/GuardiansOfGalaxy 300 1
file DC/Batman 504 1
file GameOfThrones 900 0
file DC/Superman 200 1
file Marvel/CaptainAmerica 342 0
```

**file2.txt**

```
file Science/Biology 200 1
file Math/Calculus 342 0
file Psychology 324 1
file Anthropology 234 0
file Science/Chemistry 444 1
```

**(As you can tell by the format, the third tab is the **views**)

The **output** should look like this:

```
file GameOfThrones 900 0
file DC/Batman 504 1
file Science/Chemistry 444 1
file Marvel/CaptainAmerica 342 0
file Math/Calculus 342 0 
...
```

Aside from that here is the function I am currently working on to display the top views :

```
records = dict(re.findall(r"files (.+) (\d+).+", files))
main_dict = {}

for file in records:
    print(file)
    #idk how to display the top views

return main_dict
```

Comment: Look into `sort()`/`sorted()`.

Comment: @NPE I know I can use that at the end but I guess my main concern is displaying the top views based on the strings given on my text files.

Comment: Regex does not provide any feature to get the shortest or longest or max or min values. It is used to extract text. Extract these numbers you need to sort against, and sort.

Comment: How about you read both the files, store the results in a list, and sort by the values?

Comment: @wiktor how should i extract them? I’ve never done that before. I feel since i made my regex into a sectionary, i could make the title as a key and views as value. Is that a way to view it as? But I’m not so sure how to implement that.

Comment: @dirtybit how can I sort the Values if i were to turn the regex into dictionary?

Comment: Give me a moment!

Comment: From your data, it seems you may extract each number with `line.split()[2]`, no need for a regex.

Comment: @smokingpenguin see if the answer I posted, helps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Extracting the sorting criteria

First, you need to get the information by which you want to sort out of each line.
You can use this regex to extract views and the path from your lines:

```
>>> import re
>>> criteria_re = re.compile(r'file (?P<path>\S*) (?P<views>\d*) \d*')
>>> m = criteria_re.match('file GameOfThrones 900 0')
>>> res = (int(m.group('views')), m.group('path'))
>>> res
(900, 'GameOfThrones')
```

#### Sorting

Now the whole thing just needs to be applied to your file collection. Since we don't want a default search, we need to set the `key` parameter of the search function to help it know what exactly we want to sort by:

```
def sort_files(files):
    lines = []
    for file in records:
        for line in open(file):
            m = criteria_re.match(line)
            # maybe do some error handling here, in case the regex doesn't match
            lines.append((line, (-int(m.group('views')), m.group('path'))))
            # taking the negative view count makes the comparison later a
            # bit more simple, since we can just sort be descending order
            # for both view as well as alphabetical path order 
    # the sorting criteria were only tagging along to help with the order, so
    # we can discard them in the result
    return [line for line, criterion in sorted(lines, key=lambda x: x[1])]
```

Comment: where is the 'm' in m.group coming from? I'm trying to follow your code, but I can't seem to follow the first extracting part. Is there a way you can show me how this outputs in rep.l or something? Thank you so much!

Comment: My bad, i edited the code a bunch and forgot about that. I can repl it tomorrow, no problem =)

Comment: @smokingpenguin I put my code [in a repl](https://repl.it/repls/MotherlySubtleWordprocessing), with your example files plus a few examples to test the alphabetical ordering. Feel free to ask questions if anything about the code is unclear.

Comment: Thank you. That made so much sense now.

Comment: For posterity, in case the repl link rots away: https://gist.github.com/a-recknagel/1070f39f5bc7e460a6801c41e92e9f73

Answer (score 0):

Continuing from the comment I made above:

1. Read both the files and store their lines in a list
2. Flatten the list
3. Sort the list by the views in the string

**Hence**:

list.txt:

```
file Marvel/GuardiansOfGalaxy 300 1
file DC/Batman 504 1
file GameOfThrones 900 0
file DC/Superman 200 1
file Marvel/CaptainAmerica 342 0
```

list2.txt:

```
file Science/Biology 200 1
file Math/Calculus 342 0
file Psychology 324 1
file Anthropology 234 0
file Science/Chemistry 444 1
```

**And**:

```
fileOne = 'list.txt'
fileTwo = 'list2.txt'

result = []
with open (fileOne, 'r') as file1Obj, open(fileTwo, 'r') as file2Obj:
      result.append(file1Obj.readlines())
      result.append(file2Obj.readlines())

result = sum(result, [])                 # flattening the nested list
result = [i.split('\n', 1)[0] for i in result]  # removing the \n char

print(sorted(result, reverse=True, key = lambda x: int(x.split()[2]))) # sorting by the view
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
[
 'file GameOfThrones 900 0', 'file DC/Batman 504 1', 'file Science/Chemistry 444 1', 
 'file Marvel/CaptainAmerica 342 0', 'file Math/Calculus 342 0', 
 'file Psychology 324 1', 'file Marvel/GuardiansOfGalaxy 300 1', 
 'file Anthropology 234 0', 'file DC/Superman 200 1', 'file Science/Biology 200 1'
]
```

**Shorter-version**:

```
with open (fileOne, 'r') as file1Obj, open(fileTwo, 'r') as file2Obj: result = file1Obj.readlines() + file2Obj.readlines()    
print(list(i.split('\n', 1)[0] for i in sorted(result, reverse=True, key = lambda x: int(x.split()[2]))))   # sorting by the view
```

Comment: can't I use import glob to open those two .txt files as well?

Comment: wait where can I see that way?

Comment: @smokingpenguin What I meant was, I showed `my` way. and since that was not asked/mentioned in the original question I attempted with it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code:

```
#open the 2 files in read mode
with open('file1.txt', 'r') as f1, open('file2.txt', 'r') as f2:
  data = f1.read() + f2.read() #store the content of the two files in a string variable
  lines = data.split('\n') #split each line to generate a list
  #do the sorting in reverse mode, based on the 3rd word, in your case number of views
  print(sorted(lines[:-1], reverse=True, key=lambda x:int(x.split()[2])))
```

**output:**

```
['file GameOfThrones 900 0', 'file DC/Batman 504 1', 'file Science/Chemistry 444 1', 'file Marvel/CaptainAmerica 342 0', 'file Math/Calculus 342 0', 'file Psychology 324 1', 'file Marvel/GuardiansOfGalaxy 300 1', 'file Anthropology 234 0', 'file DC/Superman 200 1', 'file Science/Biology 200 1']
```